# A confusion about find the boundary of a set $E = D \times E_x$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ and $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^1 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, bounds-of-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich, at page 132, it is given that

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, in the **proof of the Remark**, I couldn't understand how does the author conclude that $\partial E$ is the graphs of $\phi_i$ and $Z$, which is a portion of the product of the boundary $\partial D$ and a sufficiently large one-dimensional closed interval of length $l$ ?

**Edit:**

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks a lot, I thing you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\partial(A×B)=((\partial A)×B)∪(A×(\partial B))$ (which looks a lot like the product formula for derivatives, which is no coincidence!)

I believe that the two terms the author describes are exactly these, since $B$ in this case is an interval, so $\partial B$ consists of two points (which end up corresponding to the two graphs).